# How To Transpose matrix list

Tags: python, list, matrix, transpose

I am trying to Transpose matrix list but error:

```
def transpose_matriks(mat_a):
  def wrapper():
      temp_row = []
      temp_mat = []
      for i in range(0, pjg_matriks(mat_a)):
        for j in range(0, lbr_matriks(mat_a)):
          temp_row.append( mat_a[j][i])
        temp_mat.append(temp_row)
        temp_row = []
      return temp_mat
  return wrapper

@transpose_matriks
def matrixY():
  X = [3,2,4,5]
  return matrixY

print(matrixY())
```

erorr problem TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len() :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS X441U\PycharmProjects\PfModul4\coba.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(matrixX())
  File "C:\Users\ASUS X441U\PycharmProjects\PfModul4\coba.py", line 4, in wrapper
    rows = len (matrix)
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

the output should be like this

```
 matrixY = [3,4,2,5]
```

Comment: You should give more examples. What is the logic: always two colums or always two rows, or try a square shape?

Comment: I've added some examples and error sections